# Postgresql loop through onequery to create results for another query

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I am using Postgresql 9.6 and want to know if this is even possible.

I have a query similar to this:

```
with mkt_types as (
    select distinct(mkt_medium)
    from sessions
), sessions_all as (
    select *
    from sessions
)
select
        count(visitor_id) as total_visits, 
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'seo') as seo_visitors, 
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'seo' and domain_sessionidx = 1) as seo_new_visitors,
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'seo' and conversion_visit = 'true') as seo_converters,
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'seo' and domain_sessionidx = 1 and conversion_visit = 'true') as seo_new_converters
    from sessions_all;
```

Is it possible to get the values from mkt_types and loop through the results and replace the 'seo' part of the query.

EXAMPLE
If I have mkt_types 'seo', 'email', 'banner' then my final query would end up with the result of if I had typed out:

```
with mkt_types as (
    select distinct(mkt_medium)
    from sessions
), sessions_all as (
    select *
    from sessions
)
select
        count(visitor_id) as total_visits, 
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'seo') as seo_visitors, 
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'seo' and domain_sessionidx = 1) as seo_new_visitors,
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'seo' and conversion_visit = 'true') as seo_converters,
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'seo' and domain_sessionidx = 1 and conversion_visit = 'true') as seo_new_converters,
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'email') as email_visitors, 
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'email' and domain_sessionidx = 1) as email_new_visitors,
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'email' and conversion_visit = 'true') as email_converters,
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'email' and domain_sessionidx = 1 and conversion_visit = 'true') as email_new_converters,
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'banner') as banner_visitors, 
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'banner' and domain_sessionidx = 1) as banner_new_visitors,
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'banner' and conversion_visit = 'true') as banner_converters,
            count(1) FILTER (where mkt_medium = 'banner' and domain_sessionidx = 1 and conversion_visit = 'true') as banner_new_converters
    from sessions_all;
```

Thank you

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. Writing `distinct(mkt_medium)` makes no sense (also: the `session_all` cte is a bad idea - it will slow down your query - just put the `sessions` table in the final query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view, it seems like we can not do like that. Of course you can put in function and built the query.

If you can get the result vertically instead of horizontally, I can suggest another query like this:

```
(
 select 'all' as mkt_medium,
    count(1) as total_visits, 
    count(1) FILTER (where domain_sessionidx = 1) as new_visitors, 
    count(1) FILTER (where conversion_visit = 'true') as converters, 
    count(1) FILTER (where domain_sessionidx = 1 and conversion_visit = 'true') as new_converters
   FROM sessions_all
) UNION ALL (
 SELECT mkt_medium,
            count(1) as total_visits, 
    count(1) FILTER (where domain_sessionidx = 1) as new_visitors, 
    count(1) FILTER (where conversion_visit = 'true') as converters, 
    count(1) FILTER (where domain_sessionidx = 1 and conversion_visit = 'true') as new_converters
    from sessions_all
   GROUP BY mkt_medium
)
```

Comment: This is great, so much easier than what I was trying to do and vertically works much better than how I was originally trying.